# Form disappears within ascx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, forms

So this is as should be on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uNxpE/2/).
But when I put it within a `.ascx` page. Which loads within an `.aspx` page. The `<form>` decides to make itself `null`.
Anyone know why it is doing this?

More specifically:

```
document.getElementById('emvForm').submit();
```

The above line is returning `null`.

Okay so looking at the code I noticed I am getting:

```
<form id="1" runat="server">
    <form id="emvForm">
    </form>
</form>
```

Firefox ignores the second form because it is a nested form. The id remains the same it hasn't changed because runat not being defined on it.

Anyway of bypassing this?

Comment: Is your form tag runtat="server"? then the id's are modified by ASP.NET

Comment: I don't think you can nest forms.

Comment: @jrummell is correct, you cannot nest `<form>` tags, it is invalid HTML. Can you just remove the `<form>` tags from your user control?

Comment: Yea I was hoping there might be a solution but I will have to edit the parent controls.

Comment: Why were you using a seperate `<form>` tag? Are you trying to group controls together for some reason?

Comment: This is because of our cms it chucks dynamic html between the page. It seems we have a form tag around our dynamic content sigh. @freefaller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you can better do this:

instead of calling:

```
document.getElementById('emvForm').submit();
```

Return true:

```
return true;
```

Then modify your input button to this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Form" id="SubmitButton" class="contactFormButton submit emailValid" onClick="return validForm();">
```

Now when you return true the form will be submitted and where your return false in the validForm function the forms stops the submit.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement suggestions.